# Using something other than itertuples for pandas for speed

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am iterating over a medium size dataset (441679 rows) and pandas is doing a miserable job at iterating over it. That function alone takes close to 60 seconds up to 10 minutes

```
def correlate(ES, PERF, JAVA_PID_CORE):
    mean_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['COREID','UID','TID','START','FINISH','TIMETAKEN','INST_M','BRANCH_K','L1I_ACCESS_M','L1D_RACCESS_M','L2D_ACCESS_M','DATA_MEM_RACCESS_M'])
    sum_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['COREID','UID','TID','START','FINISH','TIMETAKEN','INST_M','BRANCH_K','L1I_ACCESS_M','L1D_RACCESS_M','L2D_ACCESS','DATA_MEM_RACCESS_M'])
    for row in ES.itertuples():
        REQUEST = row[1]
        THREAD  = row[2]
        INIT    = row[3]
        FIN     = row[4]
        TIME_TO_COMPLETE = row[5]
        PID     = JAVA_PID_CORE[THREAD][0]
        TMP_PERF = PERF.loc[PERF['pid'] == PID]
        TEST_DF = TMP_PERF[TMP_PERF['timestamp'].between(INIT, FIN, inclusive=True)]
        if not TEST_DF.empty and TIME_TO_COMPLETE < 100.0:
            mean_results.loc[len(mean_results)] = [core_check(JAVA_PID_CORE[THREAD][1]), REQUEST, THREAD, INIT, FIN, FIN-INIT, TEST_DF['INST_RETIRED'].mean()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['BRANCH_MISPRED'].mean()/1000.0,  TEST_DF['L1I_CACHE_ACCESS'].mean()/1000000.0,  TEST_DF['L1D_READ_ACCESS'].mean()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['L2D_CACHE_ACCESS'].mean()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS'].mean()/1000000.0]
            sum_results.loc[len(sum_results)] = [core_check(JAVA_PID_CORE[THREAD][1]), REQUEST, THREAD, INIT, FIN, FIN-INIT, TEST_DF['INST_RETIRED'].sum()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['BRANCH_MISPRED'].sum()/1000.0,  TEST_DF['L1I_CACHE_ACCESS'].sum()/1000000.0,  TEST_DF['L1D_READ_ACCESS'].sum()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['L2D_CACHE_ACCESS'].sum()/1000000.0, TEST_DF['DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS'].sum()/1000000.0]
    return mean_results, sum_results
```

`core_check` is a simple if loop

```
def core_check(ID):
    if ID==0.0 or ID == 1.0:
        return "b"
    else:
        return "r"
```

Any optimisation or hints for optimisation will be appreciated.

Some more information: In the ES data frame, I always will find a unique ID (UID) for a given timestamp from each thread (TID). With this timing information, I would like to check in the PERF dataframe the corresponding column values and do some basic math operation (like sum, mean, etc.,)

JAVA_PID_CORE

`{80: [2690, 5], 81: [2691, 4], 83: [2693, 3], 84: [2694, 2], 85: [2695, 1], 93: [3137, 0]}`

ES DATA FRAME:

```
       UID  TID    TSTAMP-INIT     TSTAMP-FIN  DIFF
0     !!KA   84  1494831924775  1494831925061   286
1     !#f)   83  1494831906419  1494831906446    27
2     !&YV   85  1494831920413  1494831920426    13
3     !)}{   85  1494831926591  1494831926598     7
4     !*$W   93  1494831927342  1494831927347     5
5     !*3+   93  1494833162404  1494833162447    43
6     !,{Q   85  1494831941291  1494831941293     2
7     !-ap   93  1494831946108  1494831946164    56
8     !.<H   93  1494831961861  1494831961887    26
9     !/Jk   93  1494832464581  1494832464585     4
10    !/k:   80  1494831913852  1494831913956   104
11    !1)6   80  1494832700278  1494832700284     6
12    !4o5   81  1494831926623  1494831926638    15
13    !6Wz   85  1494832936660  1494832936679    19
14    !7xl   83  1494831940012  1494831940423   411
15    !8~j   80  1494831905562  1494831905668   106
16    !:/#   83  1494831932570  1494831932670   100
17    !:Vb   84  1494831930895  1494831931047   152
18    !=FY   93  1494831964176  1494831964190    14
19    !@F}   83  1494831919131  1494831919170    39
20    !@Pr   81  1494831927099  1494831927106     7
21    !@Y&   85  1494831949397  1494831949458    61
22    !BY*   85  1494831953127  1494831953151    24
23    !D/5   85  1494831950950  1494831950956     6
24    !D>.   93  1494831954029  1494831954041    12
25    !DY@   93  1494831933042  1494831933130    88
26    !No7   80  1494832598080  1494832598087     7
27    !O~t   93  1494831958937  1494831958964    27
28    !Pr$   93  1494831956491  1494831956521    30
29    !UlC   85  1494831905536  1494831905539     3
```

TEST_DF

```
           timestamp   pid  INST_RETIRED  BRANCH_MISPRED  L1I_CACHE_ACCESS  \
10244  1494831924777  2694       8451572           84144           5859557   
10250  1494831924797  2694       7793034           16479           4532358   
10256  1494831924817  2694       9711538            5354           5479005   
10262  1494831924838  2694       9417459            6447           5322698   
10268  1494831924858  2694       5827656            5117           3312970   
10274  1494831924878  2694       9752178            5781           5531895   
10280  1494831924899  2694       9627616            5503           5440153   
10286  1494831924919  2694       9680190            5305           5487293   
10292  1494831924940  2694      10195290            5477           5762275   
10298  1494831924961  2694       8258304            5837           4681574   
10304  1494831924981  2694       9668057            7684           5447864   
10310  1494831925001  2694       9676702            7085           5426614   
10316  1494831925022  2694       9784358            7122           5505523   
10322  1494831925042  2694       9081244           10005           5146579
```

PERF csv dump

```
timestamp,pid,INST_RETIRED,BRANCH_MISPRED,L1I_CACHE_ACCESS,L1D_READ_ACCESS,L2D_CACHE_ACCESS,DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS
1494831906349,3137,29998089,18347,8765597,8004347,372144,8003127,
1494831906350,2695,29794795,16212,8559232,8431582,425171,8430788,
1494831906350,2694,6030818,22909,3737737,0,245017,0,
1494831906350,2693,6146912,9282,3531230,0,186687,0,
1494831906350,2691,6654263,6256,3806089,0,91580,0,
1494831906350,2690,6235079,16255,3700410,0,199919,0,
1494831906370,3137,10177539,52101,3930006,2660383,563205,2657417,
1494831906370,2695,26730045,23757,7939065,7177029,430927,7175600,
1494831906370,2694,4835318,48355,3394955,0,354923,0,
1494831906370,2693,6188160,8343,3524848,0,172268,0,
1494831906370,2691,6579932,6936,3746719,0,97691,0,
1494831906370,2690,5339960,42454,3553089,0,323373,0,
1494831906390,3137,22703263,74115,8000304,6295892,926318,6300728,
1494831906391,2695,24147175,76240,8193916,6787613,849869,6789710,
1494831906391,2694,7059747,46404,4567632,0,395898,0,
1494831906391,2693,8378296,13639,4796995,0,242115,0,
1494831906391,2691,9031591,11004,5124851,0,149132,0,
1494831906391,2690,5986551,69506,4330165,0,553982,0,
1494831906411,3137,12902656,52133,4746982,3564058,570613,3559191,
1494831906411,2695,23827520,12880,6706918,6908672,357731,6908573,
```

ES.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 42532 entries, 0 to 42531
Data columns (total 5 columns):
UID            42532 non-null object
TID            42532 non-null int64
TSTAMP-INIT    42532 non-null int64
TSTAMP-FIN     42532 non-null int64
DIFF           42532 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
None
```

PERF.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 440117 entries, 1 to 440117
Data columns (total 8 columns):
timestamp                         440117 non-null int64
pid                               440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK          440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS         440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES    440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_CPU_MIGRATIONS      440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS_MIN     440117 non-null int64
PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS_MAJ     440117 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(8)
memory usage: 26.9 MB
None
```

PERF['pid'].value_counts()

```
2694    73353
2695    73353
2693    73353
2690    73353
2691    73353
3137    73352
Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I see 3 datasets (`ES`, `PERF` and `JAVA_PID_CORE`). Which one hase 441k+ rows, and how large are the others?

Comment: PERF and ES have 441K+ rows. the JAVA_PID_CORE is a dictionary with about 10 keys value pairs.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of each, preferably data which corresponds to things you want to sum up?

Comment: @MaartenFabré: added example data

Comment: Could we use multiprocess? and do you think that would work?

Comment: I meant a few lines of the raw data, as something I can easily import in a `pandas.DataFrame`, and perhaps also the `JAVA_PID_CORE`

Comment: Updated with more data. any help will be useful

Comment: add an `<ENTER>` after the `ES.info()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with a `join`

## Add columns 'PID' and 'core' to the ES-DataFrame

```
ES['core'] = ES['TID'].apply(lambda x: core_check(JAVA_PID_CORE[x][0]))
ES['pid'] = ES['TID'].apply(lambda x: JAVA_PID_CORE[x][0])
```

## Additional identifier in ES

This is not necessary if the ES-index is unique, then `ES = ES.reset_index()` works just as well

```
ES['es_id'] = range(len(ES))
```

or

```
ES.insert(0,'es_id', range(len(ES)))
```

Depending on whether the location is important

## Join `ES` and `PERF`

and select the correct rows

```
TMP_PERF = pd.merge(PERF, ES, on='pid')
```

Yields a 108 x 15 `DataFrame`

```
TEST_DF = TMP_PERF[(TMP_PERF['TSTAMP-INIT'] < TMP_PERF['timestamp'] + 100) & (TMP_PERF['timestamp'] < TMP_PERF['TSTAMP-FIN'] + 100) & (TMP_PERF['DIFF'] < 100)]
```

Here I changed from the `init` < `timestamp` < `fin` to successive comparisons. I added the +100 because in the sample dataset no rows were returned

```
timestamp   pid     INST_RETIRED    BRANCH_MISPRED  L1I_CACHE_ACCESS    L1D_READ_ACCESS     L2D_CACHE_ACCESS    DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS    UID     TID     TSTAMP-INIT     TSTAMP-FIN  DIFF    es_id
78  1494831906350   2693    6146912     9282    3531230     0   186687  0   !#f)    83  1494831906419   1494831906446   27  1
82  1494831906370   2693    6188160     8343    3524848     0   172268  0   !#f)    83  1494831906419   1494831906446   27  1
86  1494831906391   2693    8378296     13639   4796995     0   242115  0   !#f)    83  1494831906419   1494831906446   27  1
```

## Aggregate the results

```
results_df_sum = TEST_DF[['es_id', 'INST_RETIRED', 'BRANCH_MISPRED', 'L1I_CACHE_ACCESS', 'L1D_READ_ACCESS', 'L2D_CACHE_ACCESS', 
results_df_mean = TEST_DF[['es_id', 'INST_RETIRED', 'BRANCH_MISPRED', 'L1I_CACHE_ACCESS', 'L1D_READ_ACCESS', 'L2D_CACHE_ACCESS', 'DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS']].groupby('initial_row_es').mean().reset_index()

final_result_sum = pd.merge(ES, results_df_sum, on='es_id', how='inner')
final_result_mean = pd.merge(ES, results_df_mean, on='es_id', how='inner')
```

## Result

> final_result_sum

```
UID     TID     TSTAMP-INIT     TSTAMP-FIN  DIFF    core    pid     es_id   INST_RETIRED    BRANCH_MISPRED  L1I_CACHE_ACCESS    L1D_READ_ACCESS     L2D_CACHE_ACCESS    DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS
0   !#f)    83  1494831906419   1494831906446   27  r   2693    1   20713368    31264   11853073    0   601070  0
```

> final_result_mean

```
UID     TID     TSTAMP-INIT     TSTAMP-FIN  DIFF    core    pid     es_id   INST_RETIRED    BRANCH_MISPRED  L1I_CACHE_ACCESS    L1D_READ_ACCESS     L2D_CACHE_ACCESS    DATA_MEM_READ_ACCESS
0   !#f)    83  1494831906419   1494831906446   27  r   2693    1   6904456.0   10421.333333    3.951024e+06    0.0     200356.666667   0.0
```

## Minimizing memory

### Join with minimal `DataFrame`

Instead of doing the join in 1 big time and doing the selection afterwards, it might be less memory intensive to do the join with minimal `DataFrame`s, do the selection and join with the initial dataframes again

Here i will replace the columnname  `initial_row_es` with `es_id` and make an additional column `perf_id`. If the indices of `PERF` and `ES` are unique, then this is not necessary and you can use that instead of these extra columns

#### Data preparation

```
ES = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ES_str), sep='\s+')  # or your way of getting this DataFrame
ES['core'] = ES['TID'].apply(lambda x: core_check(JAVA_PID_CORE[x][0]))
ES['pid'] = ES['TID'].apply(lambda x: JAVA_PID_CORE[x][0])
ES.insert(0,'es_id', range(len(ES)))

PERF = pd.read_csv(StringIO(PERF_str)).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
PERF['perf_id'] = range(len(PERF))
```

#### Minimal DataFrame

```
es_min = ES[['es_id', 'pid', 'TSTAMP-INIT', 'TSTAMP-FIN', 'DIFF']]
perf_min = PERF[['perf_id', 'pid', 'timestamp']]
df_min = pd.merge(perf_min, es_min, on='pid')
```

#### Selection

```
df_min2 = df_min[(df_min['TSTAMP-INIT'] < df_min['timestamp'] + 100) & (df_min['timestamp'] < df_min['TSTAMP-FIN'] + 100) & (df_min['DIFF'] < 100)]
TEST_DF = df_min2[['perf_id', 'es_id']].pipe(pd.merge, ES, on='es_id').pipe(pd.merge, PERF, on='perf_id')
```

### Joining in chunks

You can also divide `PERf` in chunks per `pid`, do the selection, and subsequently concatenate those smaller chunks

```
def join_in_chunks(perf, es):
    for p, chunk in perf.groupby('pid'):
        df = pd.merge(chunk, es, on='pid')
        yield df[(df['TSTAMP-INIT'] < df['timestamp'] + 100) & (df['timestamp'] < df['TSTAMP-FIN'] + 100) & (df['DIFF'] < 100)]

TEST_DF = pd.concat(join_in_chunks(PERF, ES), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the job for two reasons:
- because I could not join the rows using the `PID`
- the final result doesn't join with inner.

Comment: @tandem can you elaborate on what went wrong here? did you get an error? did you get the wrong number of rows?

Comment: I could not join the two df's using PID. ES has PID's with multiple UID's and PERF has multiple timestamps for a given timestamp (INIT, FIN) range in ES.

Comment: @max-power With the extra data I could actually test the code, and I get empty results for `DataFrame.join` too `pd.merge` does seem to work. I am adapting it now

Comment: If you need every column only once in the aggregated result, but for some the `mean`, for some the `sum`, you can do this more easily by `groupby().agg(<dict>)`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: for `ES.insert(0,'initial_row_es') = range(len(ES))` I get a syntaxError: can't assign to function call.

Comment: replace it with `ES['initial_row_es'] = range(len(ES))`

Comment: `ES.insert(0,'initial_row_es', range(len(ES)))` works too

Comment: and this command `TMP_PERF = TMP_PERF = pd.merge(PERF, ES, on='pid')` is a memory hogger and kills the machine. the machine has about 8gb of memory

Could you potentially write a function like the one I wrote above `def correlate:`

Comment: This is a huge join which might take up quite some memory. Perhaps there is a way to do this in chunks, or only join the columns you need.

Comment: Do you know a way to do in chunks?

Comment: I've added a way to do the join with a minimal DataFrame, which should reduce memory consumption. I will look into a method to do it in chuncks. Can you add the input of `ES.info()`, `PERF.info()` and `PERF['pid'].value_counts()` to the original question?

Comment: Added the info required

Comment: If there are so few `pid`s, I think both methods can work, but the joining in chunks is probably the easiest. Still beware that you remove the `+ 100` in the selection for the production code

Comment: possibly you need to add a `.copy()` to the end of the `yield df[<selection>]` line because here you want to return a copy instead of a view